# RewriteRule is directing to index.php

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm Rewriting with expression

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z_]+)$ index.php?action=$1
```

mydomain/following works , mydomain/created_quizes also works

but the proplem is with mydomain/followers ! it redirect to index.php

The weird part that they all are written similarly

The **Navbar**

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link<?php if($action == "followers"){echo " active";} ?>" href="followers">Followers</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link<?php if($action == "following"){echo " active";} ?>" href="following">Following</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link<?php if($action == "created_quizes"){echo " active";} ?>" href="created_quizes">Created Quizes</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link<?php if($action == "joined_quizes"){echo " active";} ?>" href="joined_quizes">Joined Quizes</a>
</li>
```

Then included in **index.php**

```
if($_GET['action'] == "followers"){ //Followers
   include 'includes/temps/navbar.php';
}else if($_GET['action'] == "following"){ //Following
   include 'includes/temps/navbar.php';
}else if($_GET['action'] == "joined_quizes"){ //Created Quizes
   include 'includes/temps/navbar.php';
}else if($_GET['action'] == "created_quizes"){ //Joined Quizes
   include 'includes/temps/navbar.php';
}else{
   Redirect('index.php');
}
```

I really can't find where is the problem

Comment: Try to clear cookies or use Incognito mode. It's common problem when you edit .htaccess rewrite rules or URL parse scripts. Remember that this kind of problems are often caused by server caching.

Comment: yep I  faced it in js and css but I thought it wouldn't also be in .htaccess , Anyway it worked thanks ! @PaulMans

Comment: Please include the full contents of your `.htaccess` file. "it redirect to index.php" - do you mean an external "redirect"? The directive you posted is an internal rewrite to `index.php` (with a query string).

Comment: Please provide the whole .htaccess if you want us to help you. It's not a problem with `RewriteRule ^([a-z_]+)$ index.php?action=$1` which will redirect `https://mydomain/index.php?action=followers` if no other RewriteRule match after.